# Fake colors through camera

Tags: ios, colors, camera, computer-vision, color-space

in an iOS application I need to recognize colors through camera, but analyzing the problem, I noticed that different kinds of light make the colors observed in the captured picture a little bit different from the real ones. For example, under a high neon light a light blue seems like a gray.

What is the cause and what kind of approch I could follow to solve this problem of "fake colors"?

Comment: why? physics. . what can you do? not much. in some cases white balance will help. if you don't have full spectrum you can't fix that at all.

Answer (score 0):

The colors are not fake, they are just different than what you expect them to be. As @Piglet said this has a lot to do with the physics of light and white balance may help.

If you want to read more about it look at:

- Color Rendering Index
- Color Metamerism
- Sensitivity Metamerism Index
- Color Constancy

These all refer to the physics behind why different illuminations create different colors. There is also the camera color pipeline that contributes its share, so you can also read about white balance and tone mapping...